# Netbeans FTP unable to upload

Tags: netbeans

I am new to NetBeans & PHP Scripting, so please forgive me..

**Issue:** Unable to upload the php files via NetBeans IDE into remote server Ubuntu (FTP port: 21).

SSH Port 22 is working fine,even with NetBeans

**Error Log:**

***My Operating Environment***

1. NetBeans 7.4 Patch 3 is installed in Windows 10.
2. Remote server is a virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.4)

***Check List Done***

1. FTP Clients are working fine(WinSCP Manual....which I am trying to avoid)
2. NetBeans Terminal I can edit the files (noticed the port is different 22)
3. Remote folder is owned by the FTP User
4. Played with NetBeans Run Configuration Parameters [Passive Mode, Pure FTP...etc]

Any Help is greatly appreciated and Thanks is advance.

Ravi

Comment: Fixed: Thanks to [askubuntu] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/410947/permission-denied-in-ftp-even-though-im-the-owner)

Answer (score 0):

Solution Steps:

1. Edit /etc/vsftpd.conf
2. uncomment #write_enable=YES --> write_enable=YES
3. Restart vsftpd (sudo service vsftpd restart)
4. Closed NetBeans IDE and opened it again

Comment: NetBeans Log is saying file updated...but it is not actually updating in the Linux machine.